# java if statement surrounding buttons and text field

Tags: java, if-statement

Im having an issue surrounding an if statement in my code. I basically need my program to when the insert funds button (btninsertfunds) is clicked add 50 to the bank field and when the spin button (btnspin) is clicked to minus/ take away 50 from the bank field. The bank field should never ben in minus figures. My spin button should not be enabled if the Bank field is less than 50 and the insert funds button should not be enabled if the Bank field has 400 in it. I thought my code would achieve this but it doesn't seem to be working how I need it to be. My code is below. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thankyou

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class ElecBandit extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JPanel paper;
private JButton btnspin,btninsertfunds,btncollect,btnquit,btnpic1,btnpic2,btnpic3;
private Random random;
private Timer timer1; 
private int a=0, b=0, c=0,counter,number,collect,winnings,bank, winningstally;
private Icon iconpic1, iconpic2, iconpic3, iconpic4, iconpic5, iconpic6,iconpic7,iconpic8;
private JTextField txtbank, txtwinnings;
private JLabel match3, match2, onecherry, totalwinnings;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
   ElecBandit elecbandit = new ElecBandit();
   elecbandit.setVisible(true);

}

public ElecBandit(){

    setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    timer1= new Timer(900,this);
    random = new Random();
}
{

    btncollect = new JButton("Collect");
    btncollect.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btncollect.addActionListener(this);
    btncollect.setBackground(Color.pink);
    btncollect.setForeground(Color.white);

    btninsertfunds = new JButton("Insert Funds");
    btninsertfunds.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btninsertfunds.addActionListener(this);
    btninsertfunds.setBackground (Color.yellow);
    btninsertfunds.setForeground(Color.black);

    btnquit = new  JButton("Quit");
    btnquit.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btnquit.addActionListener(this);
    btnquit.setBackground(Color.black);
    btnquit.setForeground(Color.white);

    btnspin = new JButton ("Spin");
    btnspin.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btnspin.addActionListener(this);
    btnspin.setBackground(Color.red);
    btnspin.setForeground(Color.black);

    btnpic1 = new JButton("");
    btnpic1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btnpic1.setBackground(Color.white);

    btnpic2 = new JButton("");
    btnpic2.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btnpic2.setBackground(Color.white);

    btnpic3 = new JButton("");
    btnpic3.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    btnpic3.setBackground(Color.white);

    txtwinnings = new JTextField("Winnings");
    txtwinnings.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200));
    txtwinnings.setBackground(Color.orange);
    txtwinnings.setForeground(Color.black);

    txtbank = new JTextField ("Bank");
    txtbank.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (200,200));
    txtbank.setBackground(Color.green);
    txtbank.setForeground(Color.black);

    match3 = new JLabel ("Match 3 Symbols = 100");
    match2 = new JLabel ("Match 2 Symbols = 50");
    onecherry = new JLabel (" One Cherry = 20");
    totalwinnings = new JLabel ("Your Total Winnings = ");

    iconpic1 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/app.png");
    iconpic2 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/str.png");
    iconpic3 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/ban.png");
    iconpic4 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/che.png");
    iconpic5 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/pin.png");
    iconpic6 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/org.png");
    iconpic7 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/grp.png");
    iconpic8 = new ImageIcon("src/resources/lem.png");

    add(btninsertfunds);
    add(btncollect);
    btncollect.setEnabled(false);
    add(txtwinnings);
    add(txtbank);
    add(btnspin);
    btnspin.setEnabled(false);
    add(btnquit);
    add(btnpic1);
    add(btnpic2);
    add(btnpic3);
    add(match3);
    add(match2);
    add(onecherry);
    add(totalwinnings);

    btninsertfunds.addActionListener(this);
    btncollect.addActionListener(this);
    btnquit.addActionListener(this);
    btnspin.addActionListener(this);

    setTitle("One Arm Bandit");
    setSize(700,800);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(e.getSource()==btninsertfunds){
        txtbank.setForeground(Color.black);
        bank= bank +25;
        txtbank.setText("Bank = " + bank);

        if (bank>=50)
            btninsertfunds.setEnabled(true);

        if(bank>=400)
            btninsertfunds.setEnabled(false);
        {

            if (bank>=50)
                btnspin.setEnabled(true);
            if (bank<=0)
                btnspin.setEnabled(false);  

        }
    }   
        if (e.getSource()==btnspin){

            bank = bank -25;
            txtbank.setText("Bank = " );
            setIcon1();setIcon2();setIcon3();
            winnings = 0;
            if(a==b && a==c ){
                winnings += 100; 
            }
            else
                if (a==b || a==c || b==c)
                {
                    winnings +=50;
                }
                else
                    if (a== 3|| b== 3 ||c== 3){
                        winnings +=20;
                    }
                    txtwinnings.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(winnings));
                    totalwinnings.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(winningstally));



        }   



        if (e.getSource()==btnquit)
        {
            System.exit(0);

        }

}

        private void setIcon1(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            a=random.nextInt(8);
            switch(a)
            {

            case 0:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic1);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 1:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic2);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 2:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic3);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 3:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic4);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 4:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic5);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 5:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic6);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 6:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic7);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 7:
                btnpic1.setIcon(iconpic8);
                counter = counter+1;

            }


            }


        private void setIcon2()
        {
            b=random.nextInt(8);
            switch(b)
            {

            case 0:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic1);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 1:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic2);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 2:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic3);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 3:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic4);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 4:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic5);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 5:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic6);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 6:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic7);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 7:
                btnpic2.setIcon(iconpic8);
                counter = counter+1;

            }

            if(counter ==10);
            timer1.stop();

        }

        private void setIcon3()
        {
            c=random.nextInt(8);
            switch(c)
            {

            case 0:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic1);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 1:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic2);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 2:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic3);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 3:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic4);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 4:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic5);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 5:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic6);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 6:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic7);
                counter = counter+1;

                break;

            case 7:
                btnpic3.setIcon(iconpic8);
                counter = counter+1;


        }

        }
```

}

Comment: Hi, what doesn't work? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Hi it`s basically surrounding the if statements under if .(e.getSource()==btnspin){

Comment: and if(e.getSource()==btninsertfunds){

Comment: I need it so when the insert funds button is clicked 50 is added to the bank text field up to a limit of 400 when the button is disabled which is working at the min but i also need it so when the spin button is clicked it takes away 50 from the bank field which at the min its not doing its just completely wiping the bank field

Comment: also so when the bank is less than 50 i need the spin button to be disabled. Any help you could give would be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: what is your first "bank" value, before press any button?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer was so much confused and full of comments. Lets try this clear.

Try this code, I tested it, it's working:

```
Public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
//TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(e.getSource()==btninsertfunds){
    txtbank.setForeground(Color.black);
     if (bank>=50)
            btnspin.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(bank<=400 && bank>=50){
    bank= bank +25;
    }
    txtbank.setText("Bank = " + bank);

    if (bank>=50)
        btninsertfunds.setEnabled(true);

    if(bank>=400)
        btninsertfunds.setEnabled(false);


}   
    if (e.getSource()==btnspin){
        if (bank<=-50){
            btnspin.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
        bank = bank -25;
        txtbank.setText("Bank = "+bank);
        setIcon1();setIcon2();setIcon3();
        winnings = 0;
        if(a==b && a==c ){
            winnings += 100; 
        }
        else
            if (a==b || a==c || b==c)
            {
                winnings +=50;
            }
            else
                if (a== 3|| b== 3 ||c== 3){
                    winnings +=20;
                }
                txtwinnings.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(winnings));
                totalwinnings.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(winningstally));

}

    }   



    if (e.getSource()==btnquit)
    {
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```